# Optimize a function with JS and createElement and createTextNode

Tags: javascript

I've a function that passes data with Ajax, creates some posts and appends them with a script. It works perfectly, but I've not used jQuery and I'm not a Javascript expert.

Can the following function be optimized (in terms of execution speed)?

```
function createElement(data) {
  function cDiv(){return document.createElement('div')};
  var elem = cDiv();
  elem.className = 'contenuto';

  var head = cDiv();
  head.className = 'cont-head';

  var testo = cDiv();
  testo.className = 'cont-testo';

  var titolo = document.createElement('h1');
  var titolocont = document.createTextNode(data.nome);
  titolo.appendChild(titolocont);
  var descrizione = document.createTextNode(data.descrizione);
  testo.appendChild(titolo);
  testo.appendChild(descrizione);

  var button = cDiv();
  button.className = 'cont-button';
  //then.. there are more button in div.button-cont

  elem.appendChild(head);
  elem.appendChild(testo);
  elem.appendChild(button);
  elem.id=data.tipo+"-"+data.id;


  return elem;
}
```

The posts are a `div.cont-head`, where I put background and symbol, a `div.cont-testo`, where there is a title and a description, and a `div.cont-button`, where there are some buttons. Then, each `div.contenuto` has an id.

Comment: Creating nodes is quite performant. Adding them to the DOM is slow so try to avoid calling `.appendChild` on live DOM nodes. Nodes that are not in the DOM yet are fine. Where do you expect to gain performance in this code? There are some optimizations to be had that will reduce readability, I can not recommend them.

Comment: Is your application actually suffering from slow element creation? Your function seems to be totally fine to me.

Comment: No, the script works well, but it's the first time I use these instructions and I wanted to be sure of my work. Thanks for your reply :)